# If a product of topological spaces is metrizable is it true that every topological space that constitutes the product is metrizable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

If a product of topological spaces is metrizable is it true that every topological space is metrizable?
If not,could someone provide me with an example?

Comment: By "...every topological space is metrizable?", you're referring to the constituent topological spaces that form the product space?

Comment: $X\times \varnothing=\varnothing$ is metrizable for any topological space $X$. Maybe you want to specify that your product is non-empty.

Comment: GAM,I mean exactly that,I edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y$ is not empty, say $y\in Y$, and $d$ is a metric on $X\times Y$, then consider $(x,x')\mapsto d((x,y),(x',y))$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Every factor $X_i$ of a non-empty product space $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ is topologically a subspace of that product.
So every factor will inherit all hereditary topological properties (like metrisability and Hausdorffness, regularity, and many others).

Comment: Quibble: It's trivial in the case of metrizability of the product, but isn't your answer/comment just what the OP wants to show?

Comment: @Matematleta That a subspace of a metric space just uses the restricted metric which induces the subspace topology is what I assume the OP already knows. As he hasn't specified any thoughts of himself we don't know what he knows.

Comment: The restricted metric actually answers my question as well.